# How to display data by location

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

I don't need to use a Gridview if it's not the proper way to do this, some have told me to use a Repeater but I don't know how. Assistance needed!

Looks like this right now:

[image]

I want to separate it out by location (a column in the sql table):

[image]

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ReportGrid" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowPaging="True" BorderColor="#E8CC6B" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="ReportGrid_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Owes" HeaderText="Owes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Paid" HeaderText="Paid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrigAmt" HeaderText="Amt" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" HeaderText="Date" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            bindGridView();
    }
    public void bindGridView()
    {
        string connStr = "";
        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CASE Location
                                 WHEN 1 then 'North'
                                 WHEN 2 then 'South'
                                 WHEN 4 then 'East'
                                 WHEN 5 then 'West'
                               end as Locations, Name, Owes, Paid, OrigAmt, SubmitDate FROM Cure ", mySQLconnection);

        SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        ReportGrid.DataSource = myDataSet;
        ReportGrid.DataBind();
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void ReportGrid_RowDataBound(object sender,
                                                GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        }
```

Comment: Consider using a repeater instead of a gridview.

Comment: @sgeddes Any examples? I've never used a repeater. If someone could guide me in that direction I would approve that as a correct answer. I'm willing to use a repeater with assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Locations` column to your GridView control like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ReportGrid" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AllowPaging="True" BorderColor="#E8CC6B" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="ReportGrid_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Locations" HeaderText="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Owes" HeaderText="Owes" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Paid" HeaderText="Paid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrigAmt" HeaderText="Amt" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" HeaderText="Date" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

There is no need to use an ASP.NET repeater if you add a bound field column to your `GridView`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I don't want to add Locations as another column I want it to be its own section and records with the same location would be in a table underneath the location header like my image shows.

Comment: You want to filter your results based on whether it's North, South, East, or West? If so, you will need to write four different queries to get four different data sets.